# Data Not displaying while passing from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net MVC getting the model value but while passing to view nothing displayed.

## Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(plan plan1)
        {
            var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();

            string apiKey = "";
            var stripeClient = new StripeClient(apiKey);
            var planService = new StripePlanService(apiKey);
            StripePlan response = planService.Get("1234");
            plan1.Amount = (response.Amount).ToString();

            return View();
        }
```

## view

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)

</div>
```

How to display the Amount value inside textbox

Comment: You need to parse in an object(model) to the view.

Comment: **return View(plan1);** You missed the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope your ***View is strongly bound*** with the Model class (the instance is `plan1`). So, You need to specify your model in your return statement

```
return View(plan1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not passing hte model object back to view, you need to pass the instance `plan1` back to view from action, just change your last line of action code to :

```
return View(plan1);
```

The View gets information about the model object which is passed from the controller action, you are not passing it back, so there is no way for View to know that it needs to use `plan1` object state to render the View.

I hope it makes sense to you now that why it is not displaying your data.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given. You should return the model bij calling

```
return View(plan1);
```

It's better to return a ViewModel instead of your model to your view.

```
  public class PlanViewModel
  {
     public plan plan1 { get; set; }
  }




public ActionResult Index(plan plan1)
{
   var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();

   string apiKey = "";
   var stripeClient = new StripeClient(apiKey);
   var planService = new StripePlanService(apiKey);
   StripePlan response = planService.Get("1234");
   plan1.Amount = (response.Amount).ToString();

   var viewModel = new PlanViewModel {
      plan1 = plan1
   };

   return View(viewModel);
}
```